# Under the hood of the <ag-grid> element?

Tags: node.js, playwright, ag-grid-angular

I’m working with Playwright to write some automations for some tasks that I have every day. Inspecting the code I found the  element. I’m trying to locate a button element that is returned when I query some data by an id number. I’m trying to understand what the  element actually is under the hood, since I can see the elements when I inspect the page, but unable to locate the element when using Playwright’s page.locate() method.

I tried to use page.locate() with many different formats including syntax that did successfully locate other elements on the page but which are not children of the  element. I’m expecting to locate the button element so that I can click it.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Further research, Playwright doesn't support Angular framework at the time I was trying to interact with a certain web app. Found an alternate web portal to access the same data.